# How to know how many is class 0 and how many is class 1?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, prediction

I have a code that gives me the accuracy of a SVM, but I want to know how many is class 0 and 1.

Here is the code

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

clf = SVC(C=10000.0, kernel='rbf')
t0 = time()
clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
print "training_time:", round(time()-t0, 3), "s"
t0 = time()
pred = clf.predict(features_test)
print "prediction time:", round(time()-t0, 3), "s"
acc = accuracy_score(pred, labels_test)
print acc
```

I have tried this code below, but no success...

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

clf = SVC(C=10000.0, kernel='rbf', probability=True)
t0 = time()
clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
print "training_time:", round(time()-t0, 3), "s"
t0 = time()
pred = clf.predict(features_test)
class = clf.predict_proba(features_test)
print sum(class)
print "prediction time:", round(time()-t0, 3), "s"
acc = accuracy_score(pred, labels_test)
print acc
```

What am I missing? Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the confusion matrix to understand your prediction

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(labels_test, pred)
```